# Increase Speed Recognition Engine accuracy in Android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, android-speech-api

I am using SpeechRecognizer and RecognizerIntent for speech to text in android and here is my code:

```
recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-IN");
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "en-IN");
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, this.getPackageName());
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
```

What more can be done to improve speech to text accuracy?

Comment: Speech recognizer is more accurate when mobile is connected with internet

Comment: Set max results to 5..and then match from the results bundle received